# AJAX Calculation of Multiple Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have the user enter a value in to two input fields and then run a calculation on the results that would display in three other input fields. Pure JavaScript would be great, but if anyone can point to a good jQuery plugin that'd be good as well. I found one, but it only offer sum, avg, min, max functions.

They enter a value in A and one in B

```
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
```

Below, the calculations would show up on the fly in C, D, E.

```
<input type="text" name="c">
<input type="text" name="d">
<input type="text" name="e">
```

C = A * .03

D = B * .03

E = (A * .03) / 2 + (B * .03)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name="c"]').val($('input[name="a"]').val()*.03);
$('input[name="d"]').val($('input[name="b"]').val()*.03);
$('input[name="e"]').val((($('input[name="a"]').val()*.03)/2)+($('input[name="b"]').val()*.03));
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9b36/)

Comment: This works great! The only thing is if I add a , to the input, it returns NaN. Visitors will enter six-digit values like 125,000 or 250,000. Is there a way to allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('input[name="c"]').val( parseInt($('input[name="a"]').val())*0.3);
    $('input[name="d"]').val( parseInt($('input[name="b"]').val())*0.3);
    var d= (parseInt($('input[name="c"]').val())/2)+parseInt($('input[name="d"]').val())    
    $('input[name="e"]').val( d);
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vefLX/9/